# What's an antonym to "legacy"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, antonyms, programming

I am struggling to find out what the best and shortest way is to describe the opposite of a legacy system (especially in software architecture, where legacy means the system used previously).

I need to use it in software so I can create methods such as:

`find_legacy_record` and
`find_[opposite of legacy]_record`

I tried looking in a thesaurus for synonyms of [old](http://thesaurus.com/browse/old?s=t), but nothing really fit well with my use.

*Legacy* is a good term in programming, because you're less likely to confuse it to something else (*old* can also mean a previous state of the record, not necessarily belonging to an old system).

Comment: *Legacy* sounds like a lame euphemism for *old*, *used*, or *pre-existing*, so look for antonyms of those.

Comment: I've tried that: http://thesaurus.com/browse/old?s=t , but nothing really fits well with my use. Legacy is a good term in programming, because you're less likely to confuse it to something else (old can also mean a previous state of the record, not necessarily belonging to the old system)

Comment: Are there previous *Versions?*

Comment: I'd suggest that "legacy" is required when it is required, whereas nothing is required when it is not; you don't need an antonym.

Comment: Hmm.. then how do I reference the new system from within the part of the program that imports data from the legacy system?

Comment: @Autoresponder previous versions of what? If you mean of the records, then no, they are not but one that reads the code might imply that if they see for example 'old'

Comment: I'm not a programmer, so I guess I don't get it. It seems to me that the opposite of a *legacy version* of (a) software would be its *current/latest/beta* version. @Fumble Fingers might understand your query better.

Comment: What do you call the latest version - something standard?  Can you just use the "if not legacy then" logic?

Comment: Maybe someone on Stack Overflow can make a better recommendation based on actual programming methodology. http://stackoverflow.com/questions

Comment: How about simply "nonlegacy"?

Comment: @KristinaLopez thanks for the tip. I'll consider asking on StackOverflow. I don't call the latest version anything. The only place I need to reference the 'non-legacy' system is in the part that deals with the legacy system.

Comment: @MarkBeadles that's actually not that bad idea. Feels a bit clumsy in use though :)

Comment: @Autoresponder nailed it - *legacy* is the "old stuff", so the opposite is just *current*.

Comment: @Cristian: I can see why you might need a function called *find_legacy_record()*, but I don't think it makes much sense to call the "non-legacy" version anything other than *find_record()*. You'd just end up pointlessly adding "current" to every function name.

Comment: Yeah I agree. My use is not that extensive (it's a couple of methods) and getting to deep into technical stuff is irrelevant for english.stackexchange . I'll just go with 'current'. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: What's wrong with calling it "non legacy" (so find_non_legacy_record)?

Comment: Just a POI: As a programmer, your code will one day become legacy, too.  A better term than legacy or non-legacy would be an actual description of the record types.

Comment: Be cautious with "antonyms". The direct antonym to Legacy is Bleeding Edge.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Legacy* (adj.) means “inherited”.[¹](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/legacy) Legacy systems, for example, are the systems we inherited. In the software industry, it often has a negative connotation that the thing is obsolete (but not always[²](http://www.stanq.com/blog/?p=125)). An antonym would refer to recent innovations, so for that we would use terms such as:

- *cutting-edge* systems
- the *latest* systems
- *mainstream* systems
- *modern* systems
- *present-day* systems
- *state-of-the-art* systems
- *trendy* systems[³](http://thesaurus.com/browse/cutting+edge)

Each of these has a unique shade of meaning and you would simply pick the one that is closest in meaning to what you intend.

## Footnotes

¹ “[legacy](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/legacy)”, *Collins Free Online Dictionary*. This entry includes several examples of *legacy* as a noun modifier. These examples show that *legacy* always connotes inheritance, but the connotation of obsolescence comes from context. For instance, a legacy moon is apparently an astrological phenomenon:

> high **legacy software** support costs —*Computing (2010)*
>   the hope of securing **legacy gifts** —*The Sun (2016)*
>   something for the **legacy committee** to consider —*Times, Sunday Times (2012)*
>   still using army **legacy computer systems** —*Times, Sunday Times (2013)*
>   a **legacy moon** suggests something —*The Sun (2010)*

² Stanley Quayle, “[Ticketmaster and its ‘old’ system](http://www.stanq.com/blog/?p=125)”, *VMS Spoken Here*. Sometimes, according to Mr Quayle, “*legacy* means *stuff that just works*”.

³ Italicized terms collected from the entry “[cutting edge](http://thesaurus.com/browse/cutting+edge)”, *Thesaurus.com*.

Comment: None of the alternatives fits the phrase find_[opposite of legacy]_record per OP's context.

Comment: @Kris Understood, but if that limitation is added then the question becomes purely how to name the OP's variable and that is too localized. OP's stated question has the potential to be generally useful so I answered it with that in mind.

Comment: In companies I've worked in we've often used the term "strategic" to mean the direction in which we wish to go, the systems that we will continue to use, indicating non-legacy.

Answer (score 13):

Some possibilities are:

- *current*
- *active*
- *present*
- no additional word, just call it `find_record`

Answer (score 3):

Greenfield is a term that describes a software system that's starting out entirely new. Not an exact match, but I can't think of anything better.

Comment: Interesting term. Didn't know about it. I think it's too abstract to use it here, but I'll keep it in mind

Answer (score 2):

Anterograde- Directed forward in time.

Answer (score 0):

Antonym of Legacy is Provisional

Comment: You may want to give more detail to this answer.  What is a 'Provisional System'?  How/when would Provisional apply to the circumstances the OP discusses?

Answer (score -1):

The usual term used is ***conventional***.

One example:

> ...achieving compatibility between current digital conventional systems and legacy analog system represents a challenge.

<sup>[Comparisons of Conventional and Trunked Systems](http://www.safecomprogram.gov/library/Lists/Library/Attachments/239/Conventional_and_Trunked_Radio_Systems_Comparison_Report.pdf) (pdf)</sup>

However, this term is used more frequently as an antonym of *futuristic* / *innovative* / *out of the box*, that is, with reference to the future than the past. Also, dictionaries generally do not define this term in the "today's contemporary" sense.

Comment: The reason "conventional" is not found in dictionaries with a sense of "today's contemporary" is that it doesn't mean that. "Conventional" in your linked document is used in contradistinction not to "legacy" but to "trunked". Read the title, as well as the early sections which define "conventional", "trunked", and "hybrid", the three types of system being discussed.

Comment: @MετάEd "Trunked" is the legacy system. QED.

Comment: I'm sure the anonymous down voter is a gentleman.

Comment: Actually, in your source "conventional" is the legacy architecture and "trunked" and "hybrid" are later, more modern developments.