# Description word between new and old?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am trying to create a scale of descriptive words. I have new content being described as "fresh" thinking of describing old content just as "old" unless you have any other suggestions.

My issue is what to describe content that is neither new or old. Looking for one word.

Comment: I think either ELU should explicitly classify *What's the word for **average/middle** in the context of these two "opposite" adjectives?* as Off Topic (my preferred option), or we should have a specific tag for them. There's hardly ever an unambiguously correct answer - not surprisingly, since in normal contexts we simply don't bother to mention the fact that something is at neither extreme on whatever spectrum it happens to be.

Comment: But ***middle-aged*** is often used for people- not so much for content on a website.

Comment: @FumbleFingers actually the missing tags should be "website-design" and "variable-naming" and subject to the same rule as a hypothetical "do-my-homework" tag.

Comment: @JeffSahol: That's a good point. In an awful lot of cases, requests like this are only posted because the OP wants a "context-specific" label for the middle option (on a web form or similar) meaning *neither of these two extremes apply*. I assume some people are neither attracted to nor repelled by questions like this (but - wouldn't you know it? I can't think of an English word that means *somewhere between "attracted" and "repelled"* :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers but, but...there's another word I cannot think of, one that means "attracted and repelled at the same time"...like the reaction some people have to a car wreck, or the Kardashians. I may have to post...

Comment: Content "freshness" would be better represented with a gauge.

Comment: **Recent** can be appropriate, if you exclude "most recent". Also, the content may be **superseded**, i.e. replaced by new content.

Comment: Fresh >> Ripe >> Stale

Comment: I like @Grafitto's *recent*, and there's also *mature*.

Comment: What's your criteria for describing content as old or new? For example, a post that published a week ago is new or old? Generally, as said in other comments, you can organize your content in three main categories : New (fresh), Recent and Old. Moreover, it's strongly depends on your context. If you run a news website, suggestions may be different. So, tell us more about your website.

Comment: @JeffSahol: [To be **scandalized** is thus to be in a double-bind state: both attracted and repelled at the same time.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22thusto+be+in+a+double-bind+state%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) I doubt any dictionary would give that as a "definition", but you're quite right that the concept of experiencing both states *simultaneously* (as opposed to *neither extreme, somewhere in the middle*) is one we're all familiar with. So it may well have a relatively "dedicated" term, in which case I think we should be told...

Answer (score 2):

## Aging (US)

Works well here I would say.

Fresh --> Aging --> Old

I particularly like the present continuous tense, as it's in the process of becoming old, whilst simultaneously becoming less fresh.

*Edit: As per Chenmunka's comment, Ageing is the equivalent UK spelling.*

Comment: Or, if you're British, ageing.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments, [@User116032 suggested](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267694/description-word-between-new-and-old#comment676107_267777):

> #### Dated

Which I think is ideal; [per Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/dated#dated_3), it means:

> *no longer modern or fashionable*

Comment: This suggestion doesn't seem suitable to me. I'd consider "dated" a synonym of "old."

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of content you want to classify, **classical** can be opposed to "fresh" thinking, it has more positive connotations that dusty old. **Current** can be used to describe the current mainstream, so it is not deprecated but isn't novel either.

So you could have categories as : **Fresh / Current / Classics**

And to have 3 C's, that could be **Crisp new / Current / Classics**

Comment: Downvotes without comments are not either helpful or fair.

Comment: "Current" seems to me to be more of a synonym of "new" than a term for "neither new nor old." Now that I look at this answer again though, it seems like a pretty good suggestion. I'd remove my downvote if I could (the vote is now locked in until the question is edited). Mind if I edit your post to take out the "EDIT" note in the middle? It's a bit distracting. Or you could make some kind of edit yourself, of course, and then notify me.

Comment: @sumelic: I've edited tso that it is actually presented as an answer to the original question.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest ***inactive***, which can be used in the following sense:

> : no longer being used : not currently being used
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inactive)</sub>

The idea is that the content is *becoming* old by not being kept up to date.

Otherwise, to follow your *fresh* scheme:

> *fresh* → *stale* → *rotten*

---

> <sup>I still like ***tween***, but it is inappropriate in this context.</sup>

Comment: I like inactive too. The fresh-stale-rotten might make a user think a food is fresh stale or rotten, not recent or old...

Comment: I don't think this is a good fit because the original question didn't specify if the age is related to activity. Furthermore, to me, it seems like the most inactive posts would be the oldest ones, not the ones of intermediate age.

Comment: @sumelic As is often the case with English, the right word depends on intent. I offered my interpretation of intent based upon the use of the term *content*.

Comment: I can see how it could be interpreted that way. The main problem is I don't think the question is clear enough to allow a good answer to be posted.

Comment: @sumelic I would judge an answer based on its own merits rather than on the merits of the question. But, it's your vote.

Comment: What I mean is that since the question is unclear, it's hard to find a word that is a good fit. That's not your fault, but I think that as a result your answer is not useful. From what I can tell, the question is "Looking for one word [...] to describe content that is neither new or old." There is very little more context, so I'm interpreting the question as a general one. And in general, I don't think "inactive" is an appropriate word for this concept. Your second suggestion "stale" seems a little closer, but in general it has a connotation of "old," not of "neither new nor old."

Comment: @sumelic I am not trying to convince you my answer is a good fit. I am trying to suggest a word that the asker seems to want. Since you don't like the answer, you are free to downvote, but the asker already stated the word was close to what was desired.

Answer (score -1):

**norm**

> 1. something that is usual, typical, or standard. –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=norm&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Between old and new, there is the norm.

Answer (score -2):

In some IT contexts, *legacy* is used as an adjective to discuss old or original systems.

From [Dictionary.Com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/legacy):

> of or relating to old or outdated computer hardware, software, or data that, while still functional, does not work well with up-to-date systems.

Comment: If it's helpful, there is a question about *legacy* here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92382/whats-an-antonym-to-legacy